# How to set key value pair of json output in scrapy?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

```
[{"Definition": ["Hello World."], "Fast": ["10"], "Free": ["Yes"], "Name": ["Hello"], "Movement": ["Fine"]}]
```

After crawling the website using this command :

```
scrapy crawl hello -o helloworld.json -t json
```

I'm getting the above formatted output. I want the name's value to be present as the name of the json array so the output would look like this

```
{"Hello": {"Definition": ["Hello World"],"Fast": ["10"],"Free": ["Yes"], "Movement": ["Fine"]}
```

Is it possible to do this in scrapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> a = [{"Definition": ["Hello World."], "Fast": ["10"], "Free": ["Yes"], "Name": ["Hello"], "Movement": ["Fine"]}]
>>> b = {a[0]['Name'][0]:a[0].copy()} # copy optional
del b[a[0]['Name'][0]]['Name']
>>> b
{'Hello': {'Definition': ['Hello World.'], 'Fast': ['10'], 'Free': ['Yes'], 'Movement': ['Fine']}}
```

Edit in response to your comment:

```
>>> a = [{"Definition": ["Hello World."], "Fast": ["10"], "Free": ["Yes"], "Name": ["Hello"], "Movement": ["Fine"]}]
>>> b = {a[0]['Name'][0]:{k:v[0] for k,v in a[0].items()}}
>>> del b[a[0]['Name'][0]]['Name']
>>> b
{'Hello': {'Definition': 'Hello World.', 'Fast': '10', 'Free': 'Yes', 'Movement': 'Fine'}}
```

Comment: Thank You. What if I want to do it in my spider class so that I don't have to write codes for individual json file.

Comment: @Rahul Can you write a function for this code and incorporate it into your class?

Comment: See the thing is after running the crawler I'm getting this output in a json format. I'm not understanding how I can do this without getting output.

Comment: I believe I understand. So you want a python program you can pipe the output to which will give you your desired output? Or are you storing the original outputs in a file?

Comment: Well, I'm storing the original outputs to a json file but I want it to be in the format that I gave. The first output is the original one. I want to manipulate it so that I can get my desired output.

Comment: Hey, Thank you. Finally I figured it out using your suggestion.

Comment: Hey timgeb, I need a little bit of help here again. I want the value of the key to be in string not in json array. I tried but couldn't make it work. Can you suggest something.
the output will be like:
{'Hello': {'Definition': 'Hello World.', 'Fast': '10', 'Free': 'Yes', 'Movement': 'Fine'}}